# DKPro Core Groovy usage and installation with UIMA

Tags: java, groovy, nlp, uima, dkpro-core

Hey i am an extreme noblet on groovy, i just found out it existed. I installed it on a centos 5 system and these are the versions

```
Groovy Version: 2.3.0 JVM: 1.7.0_55 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

then i tried to run a simple script found [here](https://code.google.com/p/dkpro-core-asl/wiki/DKProGroovyCookbook#Identify_named_entities) without downloading or installing or including anything else. The run fails with the following result. What am i doing wrong?

```
    SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:394)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:298)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:568)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:410)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:343)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:267)
        at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:170)
        at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:99)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:177)
        at gvy.run(gvy.gvy:22)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:258)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:502)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:491)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:627)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:379)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:365)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:124)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:106)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)
Caused by: org.apache.uima.cas.CASRuntimeException: JCas type "de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Token" used in Java code,  but was not declared in the XML type descriptor.
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getType(JCasImpl.java:412)
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.TOP.<init>(TOP.java:92)
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.AnnotationBase.<init>(AnnotationBase.java:53)
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.tcas.Annotation.<init>(Annotation.java:54)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Token.<init>(Token.java:53)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.SegmenterBase.createToken(SegmenterBase.java:241)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp.StanfordSegmenter.process(StanfordSegmenter.java:93)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.SegmenterBase.process(SegmenterBase.java:124)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:378)
        ... 34 more

May 07, 2014 12:36:27 AM org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl processAndOutputNewCASes(273)
SEVERE: Exception occurred
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:394)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:298)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:568)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:410)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:343)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:267)
        at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:170)
        at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:99)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:177)
        at gvy.run(gvy.gvy:22)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:258)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:502)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:491)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:627)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:379)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:365)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:124)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:106)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)
Caused by: org.apache.uima.cas.CASRuntimeException: JCas type "de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Token" used in Java code,  but was not declared in the XML type descriptor.
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getType(JCasImpl.java:412)
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.TOP.<init>(TOP.java:92)
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.AnnotationBase.<init>(AnnotationBase.java:53)
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.tcas.Annotation.<init>(Annotation.java:54)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Token.<init>(Token.java:53)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.SegmenterBase.createToken(SegmenterBase.java:241)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp.StanfordSegmenter.process(StanfordSegmenter.java:93)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.SegmenterBase.process(SegmenterBase.java:124)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:378)
        ... 34 more

Caught: org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.
org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: Annotator processing failed.
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:394)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:298)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:568)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:410)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:343)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:267)
        at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:170)
        at org.apache.uima.fit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:191)
        at gvy.run(gvy.gvy:22)
Caused by: org.apache.uima.cas.CASRuntimeException: JCas type "de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Token" used in Java code,  but was not declared in the XML type descriptor.
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getType(JCasImpl.java:412)
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.TOP.<init>(TOP.java:92)
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.cas.AnnotationBase.<init>(AnnotationBase.java:53)
        at org.apache.uima.jcas.tcas.Annotation.<init>(Annotation.java:54)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.type.Token.<init>(Token.java:53)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.SegmenterBase.createToken(SegmenterBase.java:241)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp.StanfordSegmenter.process(StanfordSegmenter.java:93)
        at de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.segmentation.SegmenterBase.process(SegmenterBase.java:124)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
        at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:378)
        ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with Groovy 2.3. I can reproduce the problem with this configuration:

```
Groovy Version: 2.3.0 JVM: 1.8.0 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
```

However, these configurations works for me:

```
Groovy Version: 2.1.8 JVM: 1.8.0 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
Groovy Version: 2.2.2 JVM: 1.8.0 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
```

Thanks for reporting this, we will try to track this problem down. Meanwhile, please use Groovy 2.1.x or 2.2.x.

*Disclosure: I am a developer on DKPro Core and the author of said script.*

Comment: I have updated the scripts page with a warning about Groovy 2.3.0.

Comment: Can you report this on the groovy user mailing list?

Comment: My plan was to try tracking it down in more detail and then opening an issue in the Groovy issue tracker. Thinking about it, however, I think the script is already not a bad initial test case. Meanwhile I set up an issue for uimaFIT: [UIMA-3808](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/UIMA-3808)

Comment: Did more diagnosis and opened an issue on the Groovy tracker: [GROOVY-6768](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6768)

Comment: Using Groovy 2.3.2, I can run the DKPro Core scripts again. The issue was marked as fixed for Groovy 2.3.1, so that probably also works. Seems like the only bad version is Groovy 2.3.0.